# tinyMCE image output

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

i'm using TinyMCE for custom insert image, the problem is when i insert image with advimage, example

```
http://mysite/folder/image.jpg
```

but the image link when it loads become

```
<img title="" src="../../image.jpg" alt=" " width="450" height="581" />
```

how can i get the output to become like

```
<img title="" src="http://mysite/folder/image.jpg" alt=" " width="450" height="581" />
```

sorry for my bad english

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at one of moxiecodes tinymce example pages:
http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/url_conversion.php

I guess this will show you how to configure your tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        convert_urls : false,
```

...